# How to hide document area between panels in DockPanelSuite

Tags: c#, winforms, dockpanel-suite

I am trying to develop an interface using DockPanelSuite with only a left and right window (I want them to look the same). When using DockPanelSuite you cannot set the width of the document area and there is a gap between the panels (see the green area in image below). Does anyone know how to hide or remove the document are for DockPanel Suite? Below is the code I use to show the panels.

```
dockPanel.DockRightPortion = .75;
dockPanel.DockLeftPortion = .25;
_libraryBrowser.Show(dockPanel, DockState.DockLeft);
_pageDisplay.Show(dockPanel, DockState.DockRight);
```

[image: Gap in between forms]

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered a similar issue a long time ago, the only way I found to solve it is to change how the bigger panel is shown. In your case:

```
_libraryBrowser.Show(dockPanel, DockState.Document);
_pageDisplay.Show(dockPanel, DockState.DockRight);
```

I know that probably is not what you expect to do, but is a way to solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks - I tried something similar, but it doesn't quite give me what I want. I'll keep looking!

Comment: If you find something better please share here your solution, I'm really interested!

Comment: I've decided to switch to WPF and use AvalonDock, as it supports what my application needs.